# Raspberry Pi as a VPN client for half the network

Tags: vpn, routing, home-networking, raspberry-pi, openwrt

I'd like to connect network according to the below topology, I don't really know where to start apart from installing OpenWRT on the Pi and then setting a static address. The idea is to have a VPN client (Windscribe, NordVPN, or ExpressVPN) running on the Pi, and route all traffic from `eth1`, destined for the internet, to go through the VPN, then to the ISP's router, and yet retain local connectivity between devices connected to `eth0` and `eth1`. I'm worried that setting `eth0`'s interface as the WAN will trigger unnecessary firewall rules stopping genuine traffic, as I want to be able to use SSH and a web server on the Pi. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

### Topology:

[image: Image of the destined network topology, consisting of a PlayStation 4 connected via a Raspberry Pi device on interface eth 1, which is to be the VPN passthrough, through to the ISP router, connected via interface eth 0. Connected to it are DHCP clients, with listed examples of 2 PC's and a TV. The ISP router is also a wireless access point. The ISP router is connected to the Internet.]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you have to either 1) sacrifice LAN device access (as the VPN's are designed to intercept your connection, and to passthrough all traffic thru their network, bypassing yours. Although half-tunnel VPNs do exist, it would defeat the point of protecting all of your traffic and concealing your IP address) or 2) use some sort of feature like [Proxy Gateway from Windscribe](https://windscribe.com/features/proxy-gateway). For the former, you can use [this guide](https://gist.github.com/DinkDonk/5c3d30d5789398a3d203) (just replace `eth0` with `eth1` and `wan0` with `eth0`). You would probably need some sort of premium subscription to be able to use an external client with some providers, so be on the lookout for that.

[Diagram shown here of how the connection would be implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiwN4.png) <sup>Apologies for the bad selection of icons, Visio doesn't have much of a PlayStation in its stencil library.</sup>

Comment: Thank you, cannot I write some rules, sending internet traffic through vpn and route local as it is?

Comment: That could be possible, but it would be extremely complicated, as you would have to disable full routing/masquerading, and redirect certain traffic to the tun interface/VPN route, and certain traffic to the eth0 interface/LAN route. What exactly are you trying to achieve with this? What devices need routed and why LAN access? This can assist me in finding out how to implement what you are looking for.

Comment: Play ps4 on different servers, when is quiet on UK servers , connect to US, or Asia, Russia

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you need LAN access? From what I’m taking here, unless you are using a 1) multi platform server, 2) a MITM server, or 3) a DLNA or Plex server, there isn’t any real need for LAN access. Regardless, the latter of the two options I listed should allow you LAN access anyway. You just need to run Windscribe on the Pi or any other device, setup the PS4 to route traffic thru said proxy, and you should have LAN access from what I understand.

Comment: No there isn't particular reason, I just thought it will be easy to implement 

Comment: It would be easier to implement your VPN setup without LAN access then. Sorry to disappoint! (see the guide I added in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

don't entirely agree with @garretstand .

Certainly doing this is nontrivial, but if you are OK with devices being on the same LAN but different network segments you do this without any proxying as long as you are OK with asymmetric routing.

The limit is that while SSH and accessing devices by IP will work, devices that rely on the LAN for network discovery (like filesharing and printer sharing like to do) won't work - although you should be able to specify IP addresses and make things work.

The real knowledge requirement is in setting the Pi up as a router. You need to enable IP forwarding (BUT NOT NAT) and set it up the VPN with its default gateway.

Next set eth0 on a different non-iverlapping subnet to eth0 and configure the Pi as a DHCP server for devices behind eth1

The trick is to assign eth0 on the Pi a static IP and set up the router to forward traffic for eth1 specifying the Pi eth0 IP as the gateway.

In this way traffic from devices behind eth1 will route onto eth0 land because there is a route for the local network which is more specific then the VPN catchall.  Traffic from devices behind the router will send traffic for devices behind eth1 to the router which will know to forward them to the Pi thanks to the static route.

Its worth pointing out that most SOHO routers will only NAT the WAN interface, so the traffic on your 2 man subnets won't be batted.